# Can't type to search on ngx-mat-select-search

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have this issue with searching while using ngx-mat-select-search. I can show the options but I can't type in other to search. I type but nothing I type appears on screen.

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```html
<div *ngIf="testForStack()" class="test-form-group mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="test-form-clientId" class="test-form-lbl test-form-lbl--required">
                            {{'CLIENTE.RESPONSIBLE' | translate}}
                        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-1">
      <mat-form-field class="test-form-field">
        <mat-select id="test-form-origin" formControlName="client" required>
          <mat-option>
            <ngx-mat-select-search ngDefaultControl [formControl]="client" noEntriesFoundLabel="No results found" placeholderLabel="Search" attr.aria-label="{{'GERAL.RESPONSAVEL' | translate}}" (change)="filterByTest($event)">
              <mat-icon ngxMatSelectSearchClear>delete</mat-icon>
            </ngx-mat-select-search>
          </mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredClientsData" [value]="item">{{item.code}} - {{item.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="test-form-clientName" class="test-form-lbl">
                            {{'CLIENTE.NOME_DO_CLIENTE' | translate}}
                        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-1">
      <label id="test-form-clientName">{{clientName}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Where search should be]

Comment: Hi, can you more specify your problem? *I type but nothing I type appears on screen.* Is it the inputted text not showing on the textbox, or the options not filtered based on inputted text?

Comment: The inputted text is not showing on the textbox (the textbox is not showing either). Thnak you :)

Comment: Hi, I suspect that the `<ngx-mat-select-search>` didn't render correctly. Can you specify which version of *ngx-mat-select-search* and *angular-material* used? It would be great if you can reproduce the error on [StackBlitz](https://sgackblitz.com). Thanks.

Comment: I am using version 3.3.0 of ngx-mat-select-search and version 11.0.3 of angular material. I think that's not it because I already used it on another page (same project). Sorry I can't replicate it on stackblitz... :(

Comment: @carolina-freitas, Hi, Are you found any solution for this error. or Anyone have some solution for this error. please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue in my angular application but I resolved this issue using following step which mention in below-

1. Install mat-select-search in your application using this command- **npm install ngx-mat-select-search**
2. Import the NgxMatSelectSearchModule and MatSelectModule in app.module.ts file.

   **import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';**

   **import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';**
3. if you are using **ngx-mat-select-search** in child component then make sure import **NgxMatSelectSearchModule** and **MatSelectModule** in child.module.ts file also.

   or you can create material.ts file and import all the  component then define this
   app.module.ts file and child.module.ts file.

   Taking reference from - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search-gbvzkn?file=app%2Fmat-select-search%2Fmat-select-search.component.scss,app%2Fmat-select-search%2Fmat-select-search.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.html